# LLVM JIT-compiled program cannot find external functions

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, llvm, unresolved-external, llvm-ir

My program which JIT compiles a LLVM IR module and calls a function `foo` defined therein fails at runtime if `foo` uses an externally-defined function:

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'glutInit' which could not be resolved!
```

My program:

```
// foo1.cpp
#include <GL/glut.h>

extern "C" void foo()
{
  glutInit(0,0);
}

// foo2.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h>
#include <llvm/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h>
#include <llvm/Support/IRReader.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <llvm/Support/MemoryBuffer.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/JIT.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/RuntimeDyld.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  using namespace llvm;
  InitializeNativeTarget();

  LLVMContext context;
  SMDiagnostic error;

  std::ifstream ir_file("foo1.s");
  std::string ir((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ir_file)),
                 (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

  Module *m = ParseIR(MemoryBuffer::getMemBuffer(StringRef(ir)), error, context);
  if(!m)
  {
    error.print(argv[0], errs());
  }

  ExecutionEngine *ee = ExecutionEngine::create(m);

  Function *func = ee->FindFunctionNamed("foo");
  if(func == 0)
  {
    std::cerr << "Couldn't find Function foo" << std::endl;
    std::exit(-1);
  }

  typedef void (*fcn_ptr)();
  fcn_ptr foo = reinterpret_cast<fcn_ptr>(ee->getPointerToFunction(func));
  foo();
  delete ee;

  return 0;
}
```

Here's how I build my program:

```
$ clang -S -emit-llvm foo1.cpp
$ g++ -rdynamic foo2.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags` `llvm-config --libs` `llvm-config --ldflags` -lglut
```

The output:

```
$ ./a.out 
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'glutInit' which could not be resolved!
```

It fails with a similar error any time I try to use an externally-defined function which is not in the C++ standard library (e.g., `printf`, `malloc`, & `free` are no problem). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that `glutInit` was linked into `a.out`. If your host code (the thing executing the JIT) didn't call it, it could have been nixed by the linker. If that's the case, you have to add a dummy reference to it or use linker scripts / flags.

Comment: Thanks, printing out the address of `glutInit` is sufficient to make the JIT succeed, so it does look like the linker is dropping the symbol. I thought that the `-rdynamic` flag is sufficient to retain unreferenced symbols?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the command line option `-Wl,-no-as-needed` immediately before `-lglut` will prevent the linker from dropping the `glut` library, which it otherwise thinks is not needed:

```
$ g++ -rdynamic foo2.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags` `llvm-config --libs` `llvm-config --ldflags` -Wl,-no-as-needed -lglut
```