# How compile a llvm code file using functions from C?

Tags: c, llvm, check-framework

Is there a way for compile a file in llvm (*.ll) that uses functions in C?

I created a test using [check C](http://sourceforge.net/projects/check/) and I compile it as:

```
$clang  counter_i.c counter_test_check.c   -lcheck
```

This way, I am using the libraries from check, but I need produce the llvm code that uses the library from check. When I try this command:

```
$clang -S -emit-llvm counter_i.c counter_test_check.c
```

and try execute the code:

```
$lli-mp-3.5 counter_test_check.ll
```

I receive this answer:

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'srunner_create' which could not be resolved!
```

I think that a solution is do something as:

```
$clang -S -emit-llvm counter_i.c counter_test_check.c   -lcheck
```

But it is not supported.

I am thinking that a similar answer is available at:[LLVM JIT-compiled program cannot find external functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173414/llvm-jit-compiled-program-cannot-find-external-functions)

Comment: You mean decompile maybe? If I may also ask - why?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with:

```
clang -S -emit-llvm -c counter_test_check.c counter_i.c  
clang -o executable counter_test_check.ll counter_i.ll  -lcheck
./executable
```

It does the compilation in two steps and this way I can use other llvm source file.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, LLVM has a C interface (although there may be some limitations compared to the C++ API):

http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/group__LLVMC.html

Comment: Thanks for fixing the link!